# Connect mongodb server via robomongo from another PC

Tags: mongodb, meteor, robo3t

I am using mongodb database for my meteor app. I want to access it from another pc. I have mounted my local as a virtual drive on other PC using ssh. Now I want to connect to mongodb via robomongo. I have given the address as 192.168.1.2:4001 (ip addr of local : port on which meteor is running +1).  But its giving an error 'Unable to connect to mongodb'.  How to proceed?

Comment: Can you make clear what you use port 4001 for? What is your SSH port? Which SSH-connection settings you are using in robomongo? I use robomongo with many SSH tunnels to Mongo's, it works great for me once configured correctly.

Comment: I am using ssh to just connect with other pc. ssh -X uname@ipaddr. I am running meteor app on 4000 and hence port 4001 for mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around is to start your meteor on a regular mongo server with this command :

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/nameOfDatabase meteor
```

Be sure to have a running mongo on localhost and to change the `nameOfDatabase`.

Now it's just a regular mongoDB server to connect. Also you might need to add login and password to that mongo url and the `debug` parameter after meteor if you use packages like meteor toys.

Answer (score 0):

Please check mongodb's config file /etc/mongod.conf and comment out bind ip

```
net:
   #bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 4001
```

Restart mongodb service. This will allow mongodb to bind to ip's other than localhost.